# Laravel 4 How to pick random language string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and I am creating an authentication app. I am stuck in a very small feature I want to implement but for me it's needed. When the user logs in I want to display a random array of "greetings" like "Howdly, username" or "Hey there, username" etc. from my language file. Is there any way I could do that?

I tried something like that:

```
{{ array_rand(trans('en.greetings') }}
```

But it displays the variable given for each string instead (for example hey_there which should be "Hey there")

My array:

```
"greetings" => array(
    "howdly"            => "Howdly",
    "hello"             => "Hello",
    "hello_there"       => "Hello there",
    "hey"               => "Hey",
    "arr"               => "Arr"
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just shuffle the array each time and print the first index

```
//I am creating an array here, but you could assign whatever
$greetings = array(
"howdly"            => "Howdly",
"hello"             => "Hello",
"hello_there"       => "Hello there",
"hey"               => "Hey",
"arr"               => "Arr"
);

shuffle($greetings);
echo reset($greetings); //will print the first value, you can return it or assgn it to a variable etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar use case where I had to give random string back to the user. I'm using Laravel 5, and this is how I solved it. Your language file could look like this:

```
return[
    "greeting_1"=>"myString 1",
    "greeting_2"=>"myString 2",
    "greeting_3"=>"myString 3",
];
```

I [added a custom helper](https://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1) to my application and wrote a helper method to choose a response in random. My method looks like this:

```
function getRandomPrompt($key,$params=array()){
    $key=explode(".",$key);
    if(count($key)!= 2)
        throw new Exception("Invalid language key format");
    $file=$key[0];
    $msgKey=$key[1];
    //Get all the keys of the file
    $keys_from_file=Lang::get($file);
    //Filter all the prompts with this key
    foreach ($keys_from_file as $file_key=>$value){
        $key_parts=explode("_",$file_key);
        if(($key_parts[0])!==$msgKey)
            unset($keys_from_file[$file_key]);
    }
    $selected_key=array_rand($keys_from_file);
    if(count($keys_from_file)>=1)
        return Lang::get($file.".".$selected_key,$params);
    else
        return($file.".".$msgKey);
}
```

This helper simply looks for all possible keys, and return one string in random. You can also pass a parameter array to it. Now, whenever you want a string, you can get it by calling:`getRandomPrompt("filename.greeting")`

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for something like this, but eventually I found another solution.

In your lang file:

```
return [
    'String',
    'Thong',
    'Underwhere?',
];
```

Your blade solution:

```
{{ __('messages')[array_rand(__('messages'))] }}
```